# aiogram считает фото str

Tags: aiogram, pillow, строки

Делаю питон бота на aiogram, для обработки изоображений с библиотекой PIL, и когда я пытаюсь обработать фото оно пишет:
message1 =  message1 = f.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'filter'

Вот код обработки:
(библиотека PIL (pillow))

```
if messagge.text=="гаусовский блюр".upper():
    await botik.send_message(messagge.from_user.id, "Скиньте изображение")
    @dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
    async def obrab_photo(messagen: types.Message):
        f = messagen.photo[-1].file_id
        message1 = f.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
        await botik.send_photo(messagen.from_user.id, message1)
```

Comment: Естественно, потому что в f хранится file_id, а это строка. А вы пытаетесь его обработать как изображение

Comment: Думаю вам нужно скачивать файл, чтобы сделать то что вы хотите. `await message.photo[-1].download(destination_dir=f"downloads/{message.photo[-1].file_id}")` а потом открыть его и редачить

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос (я новичок в питон),   но что делать потом,  тоесть это сохраняется в какую-то переменную или как

Comment: Это сохраняется в папку download/ **файл айди фотки** /сама_фотка. Вам нужно просто открыть этот файл как обычное и сделать с ним что вы хотели

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вы очень помогли

Comment: Тогда закрывайте вопрос, он бесполезен для других